# Casual writing to express that someone is thinking of something?

Tags: writing, formality

In casual writing we often use the colon to express that people are talking. Example:

> Tom: hi
>   Mary: hi

I'm wondering what about if it is Tom thought of something instead of Tom talking? Like is this valid, or is there a better way to express this:

> Tom thought: asdasd

Comment: This seems a question for writers.SE.

Comment: Related: [Use quotation marks for internal monologue?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14890/use-quotation-marks-for-internal-monologue)

Comment: @kia it will be off topic in writers.SE

Comment: @Reg casual writing is the keyword here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual answer is:

> **(thinks) in braces,**

or, in some situations you can use an ellipsis, or, you can use italics,
or you can use < pointy braces >.  So, here's the "standard" way...

Tom: I love you.
Tim (thinks): Did he just say that?
Tom: I said I love you, dude!
Tim: Well, whoa!
Tom (thinks): But what next??

I think an ellipsis can work well, particularly in a poetic context, and if you're context is good so it's obvious it's a thought.

Tom: I love you
Tom... *what have I said?!*
Tim: You .. you love me?
Tim... *did he just say that?*

And so on. Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

This form of writing comes out of the idea of a script. Usually in a script any action being undertaken is written before the colon — although these are usually actions, not thoughts, the same principle could work:

> Tom: Hi.
>   Mary: Hi.
>   Tom (thinking Mary looks more tired than ever today): Are you feeling okay?

Of course this relies on Tom saying something after his thought. If that isn't the case, you can include the action as a separate line in brackets, like this:

> Tom: Hi.
>   Mary: Hi.
>   (Tom thinks this is going to be a boring conversation.)
>   Mary: What have you been doing today?

Comment: @Joe - yes I understand that - what makes you think I don't?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my two coins:

Tom: Hi!

Mary: Hi!

Tom: Thinks: *Mary looks tired*, Aloud: How are you?

Mary: thinks: *Tom looks suspicious*, Aloud: Good thank you!

Comment: you gave me a good laugh

Answer (score 0):

There are various options.

> Mary: "Hi."
>   Tom: "What might she want today?" Tom thought, wondering, but decided to reply on a positive level. "Hello Mary, how may I help you?"

Or, without quotes.

> Mary: "Hi."
>   Tom was wondering what Mary might want. Hiding the negative thoughts, he replied on a positive level.
>   Tom: "Hello, Mary! How may I help you?"

Comment: erm actually all these looks too "formal"

Answer (score 0):

In creative writing e.g. novels and other fiction, there are no hard and fast rules to denote what someone is thinking. I have seen double-quotes, single quotes, and italics used to denote thought, as well as nothing at all. Italics in particular can cause confusion, because italics are also often used to denote a "flashback" in the narrative, and/or for emphasis. When someone is thinking in a narrative, the thought is un-italicised; same thing when a word is thought emphatically. I haven't seen what happens when a word is thought emphatically during a flashback :)