# Usage of "think to oneself" with quotes

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, punctuation

> "That was a dream come true," he thought to himself, "Can this really happen?"
>
> "Teaching Don to swim would be a piece of cake for him," the coach thought to himself.

In the above sentences, should the part that one thinks/thought to himself appear in quotation marks?

Tnx, Tommy.

Comment: Some styles use italics for thoughts, especially when dealing with a running narrative.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Casual writing to express that someone is thinking of something?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29638/casual-writing-to-express-that-someone-is-thinking-of-something)

Comment: @Edwin that's a different genre. Play-like stage directions do not translate well to prose.

Comment: @marcellothearcane I was focusing on the question itself (which doesn't mention play-like stage directions) and the answer 'In creative writing e.g. novels and other fiction, there are no hard and fast rules to denote what someone is thinking. I have seen double-quotes, single quotes, and italics used to denote thought, as well as nothing at all. Italics in particular can cause confusion....'

Comment: ... But [Use quotation marks for internal monologue?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14890/use-quotation-marks-for-internal-monologue) **_is_** probably a better match.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are asking whether, when 'quoting' what someone **thought,** one uses the same rules as when quoting what someone **said** ('direct reported speech'). The answer is yes: you use the exact same punctuation, grammar, etc. when reporting what someone thought as when reporting what someone said.

Having said that, the first sentence is a bit strange, and would be strange even if instead of *he thought to himself* you had *he said*. I would break it up differently, so that *he thought to himself* appears within a single sentence, e.g.

> "That," he thought to himself, "was a dream come true. Can this really happen?"

Comment: Rather than moving “he thought”, I'd change the following comma to a full stop.