# Where would the question marks fall within this poem?

Tags: poetry, question-mark

Can someone help me punctuate this line? It is poetry, which may not always follow the common rules of punctuation...

I asked myself is there such a place in the deepest part of the soul
where noone has dared to linger where deepest thoughts are kept below

Comment: If this were an ordinary sentence, you'd put a colon after "myself" and a question mark at the end of the sentence. This is poetry, so you can depart from this punctuation if you want to. Why do you want to?

Comment: If I wanted a poetic *effect*, I could place the question mark early: "I asked myself, is there such a place? In the deepest part of the soul where noone has dared to linger, where deepest thoughts are kept below." You have *soul* and *below* as near rhymes.

Comment: You should split up *noone* into *no one*.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas. I guess I'm wondering if it would be separated by three different questions, each having their own question marks, or by two and the semicolon being an afterthought of the second question? In other words,  perhaps something like this... I asked myself "is there such a place in the deepest part of the soul? Where no one has dared to linger; where deepest thoughts are kept below?" Also, would I use quotes since I'm asking myself? This is a tricky one because two thirds of this paragraph is all part of the first question.

Comment: @gayle Please clarify your question by editing the question (there's an [edit] link below it) rather than using comments, which are ephemeral. Thank you.

Comment: The grammar is non-standard (_I asked myself is there such a place in ..._), so questions about correct punctuation seem infelicitous.

Answer (score -1):

There wouldn't be a question mark. If you added quotes however, it would be...

I asked myself, "is there such a place in the deepest part of the soul
where noone has dared to linger and where deepest thoughts are kept below?"

I'd ommit "below".

Comment: The grammar is non-standard (_I asked myself is there such a place in ..._), so questions about correct punctuation seem infelicitous.

Comment: Punctuation rules for internal monologues are more flexible than for speech, so quotation marks aren't required: see this question https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14890/use-quotation-marks-for-internal-monologue