# When quoting a thought, do I use quotations?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, quotes, quotations, quoting

Example.  In the story, the protagonist is thinking about Billy putting his hands all over his sister.  It descriptive.

I had to pick three instances of sensory and i picked that one.

If I quote the thought that doesn't require quotations, do I quote it in my sentence because I'm quoting the sentence?

ACTUAL SENTENCE:2.  When the Protagonist thought, “It’s sick to think about Maguire, his monster lips and hands oozing over my sister”. I see the grope, it’s not pretty. It’s awkward. TO QUOTE OR NOT TO QUOTE.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/14890/2085).

Comment: There isn't a factual answer (italics are often used, but sometimes there is no punctuation, or quotes are used). But this is discussed a lot on Writing SE, e.g [here](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/59663/how-to-format-italicized-internal-thoughts-intermixed-with-other-text)